# How to convert .bib to .bbl for arXiv submission?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, lyx, arxiv, zotero

How can I generate `.bbl` from `.bib` for ArXiv submission, preferably, using LyX, Zotero, JabRef, TeXworks, MS Office, or some free online converters.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:latex3].  I removed this tag but added [tag:arxiv].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Compile your LyX document to PDF.
2. Go to the temporary directory where the compilation took place. If you have the latest LyX version (2.2.1), you can do this by going to Document > LaTeX Log and clicking on "Open Containing Directory".
3. Find your .bbl in that directory.

Comment: fantastic! it worked!